# Необычная тень текста: верхняя половина темнее нижней

Tags: jquery, css3, javascript

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, способ, которым можно оформить текст так, чтобы верхняя половина каждого символа была немного темнее нижней. Средствами `css` подобное сделать не получается, наверняка существует js-скрипт для такой типовой задачи.

*Важно*: за моим текстом будет фон со сложным узором.

[image: link text]

В результате текст должен выглядеть примерно так.

Comment: это смотрели ? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/

Comment: и [решение на canvas](http://simeonvisser.hubpages.com/hub/HTML5-Tutorial-Text-Drawing-with-Fancy-Colors-and-Effects)

Comment: А ещё можно сверху наложить слой но это с узором сзади не проканает...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/vLxuM/ где подсмотрел, не помню.

Comment: Если попробовать скопировать такой текст, выделив его мышью, будет эффект дублирования. А если нельзя скопировать его, то может лучше картинкой? ;)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov вот: http://jsfiddle.net/vLxuM/1/

Comment: Не-а, в опере все равно также.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov жду не дождусь, когда наконец-то прекратятся пытки разработчиков от оперы :) да здравствует webkit! Выделение можно и другим способом убрать, статья в тему: http://habrahabr.ru/post/18080/

Comment: @lampa не хочу разводить холивар, но я сторонник того, чтоб на рынке было много игроков. Прогресс двигает конкуренция и опера много делает для того, чтобы многие фичи развивались. Недостатки у нее может быть и есть, но ею пользуется огромное количество людей в эксСССР (в мире поменьше процент).   
По поводу запрета выделения текста - это просто ремарка для того, кто это будет реализовывать, что выделение и копирование должно быть отдельно отработано.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov я совсем не против, чтобы на рынке было много игроков. Но когда у меня вместо 4 одинаковых гвоздей разные закорючки - причем некоторые лучше, а некоторые хуже, то я бы либо выкинул более плохие закорючки, либо поменял их на более хорошие.